# limited "where" options when saving Word document using OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, ms-office

Currently using OSX version 10.11.3.  Prior to downloading El Capitan I had all the options that I'd see on the  Finder side bar when I wanted to save a document. see screen shot: [image: Finder Menu] and I could drill into sub folders which allowed me to be very specific to where I saved documents.  I now have a very limited number of options and I cant drill into sub folders see screen shot:.[image: limited save as menu]

I'd love if someone had a solution.  I went into controll panel but nothing stood out to correct it.

Comment: This seems to be similar to the issue in that question, please try some of the solutions in there and report back if they don't work.

Comment: Will do.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the little down arrow next to the 'Save As' field. That will expand your options to show the Finder-like interface and expose extra controls like the checkbox that allows you to suppress hiding the file extension.